# MS Graph API for onPremisesExtensionAttributes

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-intune

Quick summary: I'm trying to query MS Graph to grab extensionAttribute1 from any user that I search for. I know that I can run the query below to get an entire list of Extension Attributes but I only want to call on a specific one.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/<UserUPN>?$select=onPremisesExtensionAttributes`

I'm struggling to figure out how or if it's possible to query for a sub-property.
I am able to get the info that I want through the PowerShell SDK but would like to be able to grab the info from the API if possible.

Please and thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that calling something like this should work

```
/beta/users/<UserUPN>/onPremisesExtensionAttributes/extensionAttribute1
```

It will return value just for only `extensionAttribute1`

Comment: I feel like an idiot. I swear that I tried that but I think that I had extra request headers in there that may have fumbled with the response... *sigh*